# How browsers handle invalid/unspecified attributes on HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

For examlpe, if I have this:

```
<div id="blah" myattribute="something">whatever</div>
```

Can I be safe that no browsers will ignore (and thus render inaccessible from legacy JavaScript) the `myattribute`? I am aware that this is ugly and not standard, but is quite useful. Or if they do, would jQuery still be able to get them?

Comment: You'll most likely be able to use `node.getAttribute('my attribute')` to retrieve the value, `node.setAttribute('my attribute')` to set the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers won't complain about unrecognized attributes, and Javascript and jQuery will still be able to access them:

```
console.log( $('#blah').attr('myattribute') ); // something
console.log( document.getElementById('blah').getAttribute('myattribute') ); // something
```

However you should use the HTML5 `data-*` attribute which is specifically for the purpose of custom attributes. jQuery has the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method for accessing/setting them:

```
<div id="blah" data-myattribute="something">whatever</div>

<script>
console.log( $('#blah').data('myattribute') ); // something
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `data` attributes, they're web standard.

Like this:

```
<div id="blah" data-myattribute="something">whatever</div>
```

Then in jQuery you can do:

```
var value = $("#blah").data("myattribute");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the data atribbutes! Will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use the data-attributes [Data-attributes, HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will ignore invalid attributes.  If you want to specify your own attributes use the data- attribute as this is recognized as valid.

w3 docs on data attribute

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes